# Slicing assignment in Memoryview throws a ValueError despite having correct syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffer, memoryview

So I have this code

```
buffer_size = 190000000
start_offset = 0
b = bytearray(buffer_size)
mv = memoryview(b)
end_offset = len(record)
mv[start_offset: end_offset] = record.encode(constants.file_encoding)
```

Whenever the last statement is encountered, it throws an error like the following:

```
ValueError: Memoryview assignment: Lvalue has a different structure than RValue
```

Comment: Is `record` a str, or…?

Comment: @Ry- `record` is a string that I am converting to bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If `record` is a string, `len(record)` is the number of codepoints in the string; you haven’t encoded it to bytes yet. The length of the `bytes` object is what you need. Also, the assignment `end_offset = len(…)` only makes sense when `start_offset == 0`, and there’s no need to create a `memoryview` to assign to a slice of a `bytearray`.

```
buffer_size = 190000000
b = bytearray(buffer_size)
record_bytes = record.encode(constants.file_encoding)
end_offset = len(record_bytes)
b[:end_offset] = record_bytes
```